# Outlook Replies with Inline Comments

Tags: exchange-2007, outlook

I have a user who uses Word as his e-mail editor.  Often when replying to an e-mail, he'll insert his comments into the body of the original e-mail.  Since he is using Word as the editor, these show as  [User Name] Comment Text  in a contrasting color.  However, some users see the comments in their Outlook, and others do not.  I've tried Selecting/DeSelecting Word as the e-mail editor on the recipients, and it does not seem to make a difference.

We are using Exchange 2007 with Outlook 2003 and Outlook 2007 clients along with a few Entourage Clients.  There does not seem to be a pattern related to which client is used, but Entourage seems to be more likely to have the problem.

TIA,
Bill

Comment: my only guess is that it might be related to the Track Changes feature being turned-on sometimes, and others not? But that's just a guess

Answer (score 1):

Try this in Outlook:

1. Go to Tools | Options
2. On the Preferences tab click the E-Mail options button
3. See if the Mark my comments with: is checked.  If so, uncheck it.

Comment: This controls INSERTING Comments prefixed by [my name].
My issue is that some users do not SEE the [my name] prefix..

Comment: Sorry, misread your question...  So they see the comment, but not the prefix?

Comment: No they did not even see the change.  Looking at the e-mail, it looks like he "striked-out" a phrase he did not want, but some users saw the word in a normal font, and without the prefix.

Comment: Are they viewing the mail or a document inside the mail?  Sounds like when you view the "final" vs. "final with markup" in Word.